# MVC Action or Razor - Who is responsible for sorting the list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a List of type MyObject, and a property of MyObject is Order.

This is used to set the order of precedence when I am outputting the object data in my View.

e.g.

```
@foreach(var item in Model.GroupOfMyObjects)
{
    @* // output some HTML *@
}
```

My question is... should the sorting of this list (by Order) be done in the Action (when building the ViewModel to send to the View) or should it be done in the View (Razor code)?

The View is meant to just handle the presentation as I understand it, so that would imply the Action would not do sorting (because this is a presentation thing). But that doesn't sit comfortably with me, because I feel that I am going to have some logic for the UI in the View and a bit in the back (where I build the ViewModel).

Who is responsible for the sorting of the list?

EDIT: I want to avoid some people in the team doing such operations in the View and some people doing it in the Action. That is going to be a headache to maintain, hence why I am asking.

EDIT: The order can change. The user can create a new MyObject on the page, post the data with AJAX, and then we make a call to the back end (with AJAX) to get the group afresh, and output it.

Ah... if we are saying the View (Razor code) must do the sorting, then now we must have some additional JavaScript code to sort the data that comes back (because Razor only runs on page load). So now we have sorting code in two places.

Comment: dangerously near to opinion based question?

Comment: I'm hoping it is not. We always hear that the View is just for presentation, so I'm wondering where this sorting should happen.

Comment: Well, how is the output currently ordered? Is it always in the same order or does it change in different page loads?

Comment: I'd be in the camp that your view model should have the collection ready for presentation...so the order would happen in the view model and/or controller action.   However, I agree with InvernoMuto, you're gonna have two camps on this one. Some people are gonna say that the order you see is part of the presentation layer.  To me the view model is the bridge between presentation and domain, so its a good spot for this kind of thing. Chiapa also brings up a good point cause the architecture of your system may help determine where the ordering "should" happen.

Comment: I am thinking that sorting should be done in the Service layer. When we get the data, sort it. That way if we get it dynamically (AJAX) or just for the ViewModel (same method called in the Service layer) it is done in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do as much work on the data exclusively in the controller.
Only in an ad hoc scenario should you manipulate data in the view.

If you need specific data customization pass you own fancy viewmodels.

Separation of concerns sounds like your concern.